# Convert csv to Json Processor in Apache NIFI getting invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: json, csv, apache-nifi

When processor is trying to convert csv to json

"SOUTHWEST PLATHONG "A""

above mentioned column value is causing java.io.IOException: invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Comment: In csv each doublequote must be escaped by another one. Like this: `"SOUTHWEST PLATHONG ""A"""`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.